# Can't load images directory in Colab

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory, scikit-image

I have imported the `zip` files for the said directories, but every time I try to visualize the images with a random number I am getting the following error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'
```

The code I use:

```
img = imread_collection(os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.img_IDs[i]))
#img = cv2.imread()
img = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: Should be quite easy to solve if you print and share the result of your `os.path.join()` and also a listing of the directory it points to and finally `img.dtype` and `img.shape`.

Comment: Please ensure you provide *"Minimum Complete Verifiable Example"* as expected by StackOverflow. As a result of your removing `import` statements it has become unclear to answerers that `imread_collection()` is part of `scikit-image`.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you not have read the image(s).

1. To read an image you need to have following lines of code:

```
img = cv2.imread('./some path to image/image.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

2. Can your function read images like the standard opencv imread module?
   Can you show us the content of this function?

```
imread_collection(os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.img_IDs[i]))
```

3. You could print the result of os.path to see if the folder is without any errors in name:

```
print( os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.img_IDs[i]) )
```

4. Don't forget to mount the drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```